# Does BIOS device whitelist affect Linux?

Tags: wifi, hardware, laptop, thinkpad

Starting with 2002, Lenovo (actually, it was IBM back then) started [whitelisting the wireless adapters](http://www.thinkpads.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=737952#p737952) and other devices allowed to be used in their ThinkPad laptops. Some other manufacturers are probably doing this, too. The exact list of allowed hardware was never publicly documented.

Some enthusiasts have modified BIOS to remove these restrictions.

Do I need such modifications to be able to use the non-whitelisted hardware if I'm only going to run Linux/Unix variant on my laptop? (not Windows).

Is the answer any different if I'm only going to run Windows in a virtual machine of some sort?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The BIOS whitelist stops the laptop early in the boot process - an error message is shown similar to the ones you see when some motherboards have no keyboard or other mandatory peripheral connected.

Once the laptop is past the BIOS stage and loading the OS, the whitelist is redundant.  In fact, the OS will probably not be aware of it's existence and will scan and find the hardware as usual.  So if it boots into Windows, it will boot into Linux.

Whether you use a virtual machine or not makes no difference.

---

HP used to be another manufacturer with a BIOS whitelist.  However, I purchased a UEFI based HP laptop a short while ago which didn't have a whitelist.  Whether this is true for all UEFI systems is another question.

**Edit:** It seems that Lenovo still retain the whitelist on their UEFI systems, going by the Arch forum entry [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=158347).